# Freshly built Cppcheck-gui simply crashes

Tags: c++, windows, qt, cppcheck

I've got some issues with wrong Qt, wrong MinGW, wrong QtCore4.dll path while building Cppcheck GUI, but finally made it into an executable, which simply crashes at run.

Disassembly for problematic spot looks like this:

```
 mov         eax,12Fh  
 xor         ecx,ecx  
 lea         edx,[esp+4]  
 call        dword ptr fs:[0C0h]  
 add         esp,4  
 ret         0Ch
```

Seems like it crashes in attempt to call something statically linked. One more thing which seems strange to me: the executable is about 30 Mb versus 500 Kb in the release I installed from downloaded .msi. It just has to be built wrong.

I use latest sources from Github, Qt 4.8.5 (mingw version), though I took the MinGW itself from Qt 5.1.1. and the whole thing is going on in Windows if it matters. I just run "build.bat all debug" - and that's it. So, what am I doing wrong this time?

Comment: Qt has 2 types of libraries: release (QtCore4.dll) and debug (QtCored4.dll).Debug are with 'd' prefix at the end and include in themselves debug symbols, so thay are significally larger. So the size is not strange at all if you use qt's debug libraries to build gui (though i wonder, why?).About static build - if you want to make static executable from qt, you have to configure and build qt itself with static linking.The situation seems like cppcheck wants to build static exe and your qt is built with dynamic linking. I may be wrong, though.Please more details about your build of qt or cppcheck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official Qt 4.8.5 was built using GCC 4.4. The [downloads page](http://qt-project.org/downloads) lists it as *"Qt libraries 4.8.5 for Windows (**minGW 4.4**, 317 MB)"*. However, the MinGW provided with Qt 5.1.1 contains GCC 4.8, which is incompatible with libraries built with GCC 4.4. The symptoms of GCC version mismatches are weird crashes, like what you're seeing.

Your options (from easiest to hardest) are:

- Build your program using MinGW 4.4 (Someone is kindly hosting a copy at http://nosymbolfound.blogspot.com.au/2012/12/since-until-now-qt-under-windows-is.html), OR
- Build Qt 4.8 from source yourself, using your version of MinGW, OR
- Port the program to Qt 5